# VBA function drop-down menu

Tags: vba, excel

I am really new to VBA and I am already stuck in the set-up phase.

I was working through some tutorials and have copied all the lines one by one from the video, but the code doesn't work on my machine, although it seems to work for everyone else.

VBA doesn't seem to recognize the "value" function. Also in the tutorial the guy had a drop down menu pop up after he typed value or any other function.

```
Sub Lower()

Range ("e3"), Value = Range("e3"), Value - 1

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: use a decimal point instead of a comma, and also remove the space after that.

Comment: It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from my comment, so OP can close the question:

use a decimal point instead of a comma, and also remove the space after that.